# Flash builder 4.7 project wont update. Deleting workspace and debugfolder don't help. Any soulution?

Tags: compilation, flash-builder

I've had alot of problems with Flash builder 4.7 the last couple of weeks. The problem i have is that now my projects wont update. If i delete the folder where the debug compiles to and rebuild the projects it some how rebuilds the old version, and any changes i've made is note reflected in "new" project. I'm using xampp as a test serves.

Anyone with a fix?

Thinking of changing to FlashDevelop. Any FlashDevelop user out there with the same problem ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thought it was pretty straigt to the point.